# How to use a variable as a function parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a big noob at JS,so if my question is hard to understand then sorry.
I'm writing a program in JS(Electron) that provides a user interface for another program I made in C++, so I'm basically rewriting it in JavaScript.

I want to use this JSON variable(or whatever it's called) in my code.

```
var ShowSecondsInSystemClock = '{"name":"ShowSecondsInSystemClock","Description":"Patches the System Tray clock to show seconds","ExplorerRestartRequired":"true","category":"UI-Tweaks","badges":"UITweaks"}'
```

Then I would like to use this function where the parameter of the function "ShowSecondsInSystemClock" is.

```
function TweakParser(TweakName, NeeddedReturn) {
  if (NeeddedReturn == "Description") {
    //I'm trying to use TweakName as the parameter of parse(),but it only 
    //accepts the name of the Tweak directly
    var NeeddedTweakInfo = JSON.parse(TweakName)
    return NeeddedTweakInfo.Description
  }
}
```

Because there will be many Tweaks, the usecase of this particular function is for example

```
//I use a non-existing tweak here for the example
TweakParser("RemoveArrowsFromShortcut","Description")
```

What I want `TweakParser` to do now is use `RemoveArrowsFromShortcut` as the parameter of `JSON.parse()` but it only accept the name of the JSON variable directly and when I input the name of the  first parameter of the `TweakParser()` function it gives me an error, because the parameter(a variable) itself is not a JSON variable (or whatever it's called like).

So my question to you is:

How can I use the string that the first parameter of `TweakParser()` contains as a parameter for the `JSON.parse()` function?

Comment: so wait, is the TweakName supposed to be your JSON object, like your ShowSecondsInSystemClock var?

Comment: @basic Yes,it is.

Comment: Well you are currently passing it as a string, not the actual variable. Have you tried dropping the quotes to pass the actual object?

Comment: @basic A JSON is a string, that's fine - and it's passed to `JSON.parse` to create the object

Comment: Where does `RemoveArrowsFromShortcut` come from?

Comment: @Bergi The way I am reading the one line: TweakParser("RemoveArrowsFromShortcut","Description")   how is RemoveArrowsFromShortcut an object? That is a string going to the function?

Comment: @basic Yes, that doesn't work, but `TweakParser(ShowSecondsInSystemClock ,"Description")` would

Comment: @Bergi yep I get that but that isn't what is currently being passed so the point stands, he isn't passing a json object.

Comment: Well the problem is that when I use the parameter TweakName(ShowSecondsInSystemClock) it gives me this error:
SyntaxError:Unexpected token S(S from **Show**SecondsInSystemClock) at position 0
at JSON.parse()

Comment: @libert1quinten You need to pass the variable with the JSON string, not the string `"ShowSecondsInSystemClock"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create mapping 
like a schema `'key': variable`
example:

```
{
  'RemoveArrowsFromShortcut': ShowSecondsInSystemClock
}
```

Full example:

```js
  var ShowSecondsInSystemClock = '{"name":"ShowSecondsInSystemClock","Description":"Patches the System Tray clock to show seconds","ExplorerRestartRequired":"true","category":"UI-Tweaks","badges":"UITweaks"}' 

  var mapping = {
    RemoveArrowsFromShortcut: ShowSecondsInSystemClock 
  };

  function TweakParser(TweakName, NeeddedReturn) {
  
    if (NeeddedReturn == "Description") {
      
      var NeeddedTweakInfo = JSON.parse(mapping[TweakName]); // PAY ATTENTION HERE
      return NeeddedTweakInfo.Description
    }
  }

  var result = TweakParser("RemoveArrowsFromShortcut","Description")

 console.log('result', result)
```